# protect to react-redux stored state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm making an app with lumen and react so I learn that if I refresh the page how could I stay the user whole page but I did it with localStorage.setItem like below :

```
localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(state));
```

When the user refresh the page I deserialize the state and use it like below:

```
const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');

if ( null === serializedState )
  return;
else
  return JSON.parse(serializedState);
```

but on this scenario I can change the localStorage state item from out of app that means I did not even store any state to localStorage, I can add from out of app and I thinks it is a big security problem.

How can I protect the state ?

Comment: You shouldn't store sensitive data in `localStorage`, but the usual answer is "store data on the server instead".

Comment: it means every page refresh i will send a request to server and get the result ? or how ?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. You can load the state using AJAX, or let the server print it right into `this.state = {...}` when the page is served.